# Stubbing variables in a constructor?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to figure out how to properly stub this scenario, but i'm a little stuck.

The scenario is, i've got a `db.js` file that has a list of couchdb databases in it (each database contains tweet entries for a particular year).

Each year a new database is created and added to this list to hold the new entries for that year (so the list of databases isn't constant, it changes each year).

So my `db.js` file looks like this:

```
var nano = require('nano')(`http://${host}`);

var databaseList = {
  db1: nano.use('db2012'),
  db2: nano.use('db2013'),
  db4: nano.use('db2014'),
  db5: nano.use('db2015'),
  db6: nano.use('db2016')
};

module.exports.connection = nano;
module.exports.databaseList = databaseList;
```

And `event.js` (a simple model file), before methods are added looks like this:

```
var lastInObject = require('../../helpers/last_in_object');

var db = require('../../db');

var EventModel = function EventModel() {
  this.connection = db.connection;
  this.databaseList = db.databaseList;
  this.defaultDatabase = lastInObject(db.databaseList);
};

EventModel.prototype.findAll =
function findAll(db, callback) {/* ... */}
```

My question is, how do i stub the `databaseList`, so i can safely test each of the model methods without having any brittleness from the growing `databaseList` object?

Ideally i'd like to be able hijack the contents of the databaseList in my tests, to mock different scenarios, but i'm unsure how to tackle it.

Here's an *example* test, to ensure the `defaultDatabase` property is always pointing to the last known event, but obviously i don't want to have to update this test every year, when `databaseList` changes, as that makes the tests very brittle.

```
it('should set the default database to the last known event', () => {
    var Event = require('../event');
    var newEventModel = new Event();

    expect(newEventModel.defaultDatabase.config.db)
      .to.equal('db2014');
});
```

Suggestions welcome! If i've gone about this wrong, let me know what i've done and how i can approach it!

Also, this is just a scenario, i do have tests for `lastInObject`, i'm more interested in how to mock the concerning data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you need to stub the whole "db" module. That way you won't have any real db connection and you can easily control the environment of your tests. You can achieve this by using the [mockery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockery) module.

That way you can stub the object that the `require('../../db')` returns. This will allow you to set whatever value you like in the properties of that object.

Comment: Very good shout! I actually struggled to get mockery to work, but after searching around it appears proxyquire is very similar to mockery, and i've now got my test working! Thanks @jahnestacado! :)

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Scotty's comment in the accepted answer a bit... here's some code I've got which seems to do the job. No guarantees that this is a good implementation, but it does successfully stub out the `insert` and `get` methods. Hopefully it helps someone. :)

```
// /src/common/database.js
const database = require('nano')('http://127.0.0.1/database');

module.exports = {

  async write(document, documentId) {
    return await new Promise(resolve => database.insert(document, documentId, resolve));
  },

  async read(documentId){
    return await new Promise(resolve => database.get(documentId, resolve));
  }

};

// /test/setup.js
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

proxyquire('../src/common/database.js', {
  nano() {
    return {
      insert(document, documentId, callback){ callback(); },
      get(documentId, callback){ callback(); }
    };
  }
});
```